# SSO support between 2 Azure Bots in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, botframework, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, chatbot

I have been following the Microsoft tutorial/guide for setting up SSO between two Azure bots which is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml.  I am doing all of the bot testing in the latest version of the Bot Framework Emulator with ngrok.

I have managed to get this working correctly via Azure AD (AAD), however as part of a proof-of-concept, I want to get this working via Azure B2C.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation around about how to set something like this up with B2C, and so far I have not been able to get it working.  I have left everything set up the same as was asked in that tutorial/demo where possible (see section below for highlighted differences).

Currently, I am able to log into each bot individually via the above tutorial/demo, but when the SSO is attempted into the skill (child) bot, (via watching the traffic in Fiddler) I see that an error of **"consent required"** is returned.  This tells me there must be some sort of relationship/configuration breakdown between the two bots which is preventing the SSO from succeeded.  As mentioned, once this fails, I then get the option in the demo to manually log into the skill bot, which does succeed.

The main differences in terms of configuration capability in AAD vs B2C seem to be:

- When configuring the Azure AD app registration for the skill (child) bot, you do not have the capability to set an *Authorized client application*. Also on this screen, you do not have the option to set the consent for both *Admins and users*, therefore the consent is set to *Admins only*
- When setting up the API permissions, the delegated permissions available for the Microsoft Graph API are much more limited (only offering *openid* and *profile* whereas in the tutorial above more permissions has been asked for)

**Thus far** I have tried the following to get it to work:

- In the app registration for the skill bot, in the API permissions section, I added an API which points to the app registration for my main (root) bot
- Manually modified the Manifest for both app registrations changing `oauth2Permissions.type` from *Admin* to *User* to try and relax the scope added in the *Expose an API* screen (as changing this does change the 'who can consent' column from 'Admins Only' to 'Admins and Users'
- Different tenant combinations for the app registration (note that both app registrations are current set up as multi-tenant)

Other things of note:

- For the OAuth connection strings, these are set up the same way as the tutorial/demo above, including the Token Exchange URL just pointing to the skill bot scope
- I am working under the assumption here that if Azure AD works, then B2C should equally be able to work without any code changes to the demo project, except for different values in the `appsettings.json` files for each of the two bots.
- I am also assuming that B2C SSO in this way is actually a supported feature - there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer either way.

Can someone please provide some suggestions for why this may not be working and what may be required in order to get it working?  If I haven't provided sufficient information in any area, let me know and I would be more than happy to provide it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you click “grant admin consent” on the child app registration?

Comment: I did, and confirmed I had done this - unfortunately this made no difference and I still got the same 'consent required' error

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT did you have any other ideas what might be going on? Can you confirm for me that B2C SSO is definitely fully supported and should work?